# What is the maximum angle I can set my window AC unit?

Tags: hvac

We know an AC unit must be angled to allow runoff. But what is the maximum angle and what is the issue with having to large of an angle? I've seen people say the angle is "5/16" or "3/16" but this is nonsense as an angle is not a length.

I am installing a window unit and would like to try and get the optimal angle if there is one.

Comment: When talking about gradient, angles **are** expressed as lengths. As in 1/4" per yard or 5/16" per foot. In rafters and stairs, this is called rise and run. It's sensible and much easier to figure than getting a protractor, a piece of string and monkeying around with a swinging weight to figure angle. It's also what that surveyor's helper is doing with the grade stick. The transit is viewing an absolute level and the number at the target is the +- grade from the marker.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Ok, but that isn't the angle.... If someone says it's 5/16 how do you know it's per yard, foot, inch, meter, grape, or apple?

Comment: @user14448:  It is 5/16 over the whole the depth (inside to outside length) of the air conditioner.

Comment: FiascoLabs makes a good point - if it's 5/16 over the depth, that's not a set angle, the angle is variable.  5/16 over 1' vs. 5/16 over 10' is very different indeed.

Comment: As with all manufactured product, the installation instructions are pertinent to the make/model you're installing and are what the manufacturer recommends. What does the manual say? In this case, the rise is given and the base measurement for the run (equivalent to our foot or yard for other applications) is either the length of the case or from where the unit rests on the window sill and is determined by the manufacturer as they know what the internal structure needs. They are giving you the **optimal** angle in a manner that you can verify.

Answer (score 3):

All the window air conditioning units I have looked at—a total of about six different models—had a drip basin which is tilted toward the outside.  Or if they have a drain hose, then the pan is tilted toward an exterior corner where the hose nipple is.

So leveling the bottom of the a/c should be the right thing to do.  If it is tilted too far, that could cause water to accumulate in the wrong place and interfere with the condenser, or maybe just overflow onto the sill bypassing the drainage system altogether.

Comment: Nice to see modern manufacturing technique applied to eliminate a kind of silly installation requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Just has to be angled enough not to get water in your house.  The 3/16 to 5/16" is the difference in height from the inside to the outside.  That sort of difference seems about right to me.

Comment: I understand that, I am not asking for the minimum angle but the maximum angle. What if the angle is about 10 times the norm? Does that cause issues with efficiency or mechanics?

Comment: It is per AC unit width.  You don't want maximum or your window unit will be diagonal in the window and not sit right.

Answer (score 0):

You need some water to stay in so the fan can pick it up just a few drops at a time this allows internal parts not to overheat but to much water and it will get in your home put a small level on the outside and just offset the bubble slightly and you are done